# Why quick definatin of a Class is different from source code

Tags: python, spyder

I have been using Spyder IDE for Python learning for two weeks. I'm confused by how to get usage or arguments of a function or a class. I found there are 2 way to get the defination:

1. hover the cursor over a class (e.g., functools.partial), then Spyder will show a popup that gives the quick defination of that class:

```py
Definition : partial(func, \*args, \*\*keywords, /) -> function with partial application()
```

2. with "ctrl" key pressed, click the class(e.g., functools.partial) and editor will jump to the definition of that class:

```py
    class partial:

        __slots__ = "func", "args", "keywords", "__dict__", "__weakref__"
```

The confusion is usages of this class provided by those 2 ways are different and which one should be used?

Comment: please do not post images of the code. Instead, post the code directly and use proper formatting (applies to partial function).

Comment: @SimasJoneliunas I would say that questions about IDE usage may be a valid case to use screenshots, since the question isn't about the code itself

Comment: Note, the issue here is that this isn't the actual source code, it's a fallback pure python implementation of `partial`

Comment: makes sense. I have been too harsh. My apologies to @Falofter.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Owing to the poor internet, i failed to post the screenshots, sorry for that. You mentioned that 'this isn't the actual source code', so if there is a method that i can access the actual source code?  Or i should just follow the  usage given by quick defination popup?

Comment: @SimasJoneliunas Thank you for you kind suggestion. I'm not familiar with this website so i didn't realize that "Markdown" can be applied. As a result, inappropriate format was made.  Sorry for that and i have edited it.

Comment: as @juanpa.arrivillaga has said, every rule has to be applied properly. I am happy that you have learned of the markdown in SO (at least my comment did lead to some learning), but in your case, using the screenshots was not exactly that bad. Cheers and lets improve together!

Comment: What exactly is the issue? Both tell you that `partial` expects a function followed by optional positional arguments and optional keyword arguments - which is correct and not "different"? Can you explain (in the question, not in the comments) how this is exactly confusing to you? For example, can you show what one leads you to believe is the correct usage and what the other leads you to believe is correct?